# Sorting padding value

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring data jpa with hibernate.
Postgres is the database used.

I have an Id who use a combinaison of value.

2 first charaacter equal to the 2 last character of the year and after a sequence is used.

```
201
```

correspond to the first item created in 2020

```
1996 equals to the 96 item created in 2019
```

that work well, except if we sort...

because

In db we have

```
2041
1996
2030
```

but we display these value on 6 character

It should display

```
190096
200001
200030
```

is there a way to sort on padding value?

Answer (score 1):

I see.  How about:

```
order by left(id, 2),  -- the year
         substring(id, 3)::int
```

Or alternatively:

```
order by left(id, 2),
         length(id),
         id
```

Comment: thank, will check if i will be able to put theses operation in the pageable of spring data

Comment: in fact it's more something like: substring(cast(id as TEXT),0,3) || lpad(substring(cast(id as TEXT),3), 4, '0')

Comment: No matter how you sort it your expected output does NOT flow from the provided db values and transformation method.. You say "2 first character equal to the 2 last character of the year and after a sequence is used". Well that would that mean 2041 should become 202041, but you want 200001(?). So how do you derive that. And is it the same transformation as 2030 transformed to 200030? Doesn't seem to be.

Comment: @roberttrudel . . . You should specify the type of the `id` in the question.  Your phrasing ("2 first character equal") suggests that it is a string, so I didn't event address that in the answer.  In Postgres, you can more easily convert to a string by using `id::text`.